# How to use @OneToOne with a @Where in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have 2 entity now, one is `POST`, and the other one is `POST_DETAIL`. The `POST_DETAIL` one stores different translation of the `POST`.

(simplified) `POST` schema :

```
- ID NUMBER
```

(simplified) `POST_DETAIL` schema :

```
 - ID NUMBER
 - REF_ID NUMBER  # FK to POST.ID
 - LANG VARCHAR
 - TITLE VARCHAR
```

I would like to have the *ONLY* one of (say English) `POST_DETAIL` inside `POST` with Hibernate annotation

```
class Post {
    ...
    // annotations
    private PostDetail postDetailEn;
}
```

Any help are appreciated

EDIT:
I am hoping to do something like

```
class Post {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "REF_ID", 
                insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Where(clause = "POST_DETAIL.LANG = 'EN'")           // not working
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "POST_DETAIL.LANG = 'EN'")  // not working
    private PostDetail postDetailEn;
}

class PostDetail {
    ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Where(clause = "LANG = 'EN'")           // not working
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "LANG = 'EN'")  // not working
    private Post post;

    @Column(name = "REF_ID")
    private Long refId;        

    @Column(name = "LANG")
    private String lang;
}
```

but the sql logged by hibernate showed nothing for the where clause

EDIT: for example:
records in database

```
+-----------+  +-----------------+  +-----------------+
| Post (#1) |  | PostDetail (#1) |  | PostDetail (#2) |
+-----------+  |    refId: 1     |  |    refId: 1     |
               |    lang : EN    |  |    lang : EN    |
               +-----------------+  +-----------------+
```

I want to get

```
Post(id=1, 
     postDetail=PostDetail(id=1, 
                           refId=1, 
                           lang=EN))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this post about [@JoinFormula](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-the-latest-child-of-a-parent-entity-using-hibernate-joinformula/) and I have similar situation.

Since I only need a `PostDetail` inside `Post`, I didn't add `Post` field in `PostDetail`, my working solution is

```
class Post {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetchType = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinFormula("(SELECT D.ID FROM POST_DETAIL D WHERE D.REF_ID = ID AND D.LANG = 'EN')")
    private PostDetail postDetailEn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "REF_ID")
    private PostDetail postDetailEn;
}
```

Comment: But there will be multiple POST_DETAIL for one POST (for different language), how can I specify the where clause `lang = 'EN'` ?

Comment: I checked the hibernate log and fonud that the query's where clause is comparing `PostDetail`'s `ID` but not `REF_ID`

Comment: How do you declare the `REF_ID` field in the class `PostDetail`?

Comment: @Column(name = “REF_ID”) private Long refId;

Answer (score 0):

You should use @OneToOne annotation for this.

**Owner Side**

```
 class Post {
       @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinColumn(name = "postdetail_id")
       private PostDetail postDetail;
    }
```

Comment: I would like to have ONLY one (eg `lang='EN'`) PostDetail inside Post instead of a List of them. How can I achieve this ? thanks for helping

Comment: Then you should use OneToOne and with JoinColumn annotation instead of OneToMany.

Comment: There will be several `PostDetail` with different `lang` but same `refId` to `Post`. But I only want to have exactly one (`lang='EN'`) `PostDetail` in `Post`. I guess I need to specify some `where` clause as well ?

Comment: Each post can have one postdetail by using OneToOne, postdetail could be linked with single post only will not associated with any other post. If you want postdetail to be shared between other then you could use ManyToOne.

Comment: Check @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation. Using this, PK for Post table will be the PK of PostDetail table, also it will be FK to Post table.